# catching value of href and using this to replace other href

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two `div` elements:

```
<div class="contact-img">
    <a href="https://test.de" class="evcms-open-contacts" >
        <img src="https://cdn-cache.envivo-connect.com/license/Tw3sZjz8v/p/xckYV8bESwsZ/80x80c/xckYV8bESwsZ.png?v=2.4.84-z3p37YEER-1467970717-yZUA33Hxn" alt="F. Alexander Kep"/>
    </a>
</div> 
<div class="contact-sm">
    <a href="https://www.xing.com/profile/FfAlexander">
</div>
```

I want to get the `href` from my `contact-sm` class and replace the `href` of my `contact-img` class with Xing link. So if I click on the `contact-img`, the Xing Page of this person should open in a new window.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Yes, but I'm not allowed to change the HTML unfortunately. I just knew how to catch the right class with a click, but didn't know how to change the href. Thanks a lot for your help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way would be to change your HTML. But if you "need" to have it the way you described then check this jQuery snippet:

```
($(function(){
    $('.contact-img > a').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();

        $('.contact-sm > a')[0].click();
    })
}))(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was exactly what I was looking for!!

Comment: Why do you need `preventDefault` and `stopPropagation`?

Comment: `preventDefault` will prevent the default behavior of clicking that `a` tag, which would be navigation to the url in the href. And `stopPropagation` will prevent the event from bubbling up, since the parents of that `a` tag might also have a `click` event bound to it, which we don't want to trigger.

Answer (score 0):

The below code snippet will help you.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.contact-img a').click(function(){
$(this).attr('href', $('.contact-sm a').attr('href'));
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="contact-img">
            <a href="https://test.de" class="evcms-open-contacts" >
              <img src="https://cdn-cache.envivo-connect.com/license/Tw3sZjz8v/p/xckYV8bESwsZ/80x80c/xckYV8bESwsZ.png?v=2.4.84-z3p37YEER-1467970717-yZUA33Hxn" alt="F. Alexander Kep"/>
            </a>
 </div> 
<div class ="contact-sm">
            <a href="https://www.xing.com/profile/FfAlexander">
</div>
```

Comment: I'm very happy for all the answers in such a short time! Thank you very much!!! Also yours helped me a lot!!

Comment: @MonikaLutze Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
  var xingHref = $(".contact-sm > a").attr("href");
  $(".contact-img > a").attr("href", xingHref);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="contact-img">
  <a href="https://test.de" class="evcms-open-contacts">
    <img src="https://cdn-cache.envivo-connect.com/license/Tw3sZjz8v/p/xckYV8bESwsZ/80x80c/xckYV8bESwsZ.png?v=2.4.84-z3p37YEER-1467970717-yZUA33Hxn" alt="F. Alexander Kep" />
  </a>
</div>
<div class="contact-sm">
  <a href="https://www.xing.com/profile/FfAlexander" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case above this should do:

```
var desiredHref = $('.contact-sm a').attr('href');
$('.evcms-open-contacts').attr('href', desiredHref);
```

This can be written in one line, of course, but for the sake of answer.

Answer (score -1):

$(document).ready(function() { 
$("#main1").attr("`enter code here`href" , "https://www.xing.com/profile/FfAlexander");
});